# Electric charges on compact four-manifolds

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Textbook wisdom in electromagnetism tells you that there is no total electric charge on a compact manifold. For example, consider space-time of the form $\mathbb{R} \times M_3$ where the first factor is time. One defines the total charge via $Q(M_3) = \int_{M_3} \star j$ where $d\star F = \star j$ is the electric current. If $M_3$ has no boundary (e.g. if it is compact) one can use Stokes' theorem to argue that
$$ Q(M_3) = \int_{M_3} d\star F = \int_{\partial M_3} \star F = 0.$$

I wonder what happens for general four-manifolds $M_4$, especially in the case that the third Betti number is zero (otherwise one can simply integrate over a three-cycle). Is there a sensible way to define charge in the above sense? Can one argue that it has to vanish if $\partial M_4 = 0$?

Comment: in a sense charges express *defects*, *non-linearities*, *spikes*, *non-compactness* of a manifold (for lack of better word).

Comment: Total charge is only defined on a spatial slices and there can be an exeptions from the fact mentioned in this question in case of ABJ anonaly as explained [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/24074/electric-charges-on-compact-four-manifolds?show=24089#a24089)

Comment: The case of compact manifolds without a boundary is extremely dull. If we allow boundaries, things become much more interesting as in Alvarez and Olive https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0303229v1

Comment: Are you still intereseted in an answer?

Comment: @Creo, yes. If you have answer, please, post here

Comment: @Nikita I have recently posted an answer to a similar question on definition of charge in GR. Have a look if you are interested. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/695745/charge-invariance-law-in-gr/695842#695842

Comment: Closely related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604217/226902

Answer (score 0):

Charge integral makes a point only in that the sum of all charges is zero. The difference to the open $R^3$ is, that there are no counter charges at spacelike  $\infty$.

For all practical purposes one can distribute the excess charges outside  a large sphere. Faraday and Maxwell could rely simply on the polarizabilty of the walls of their laboratory.