# Gauss's Law with Periodic Boundary Conditions- Why No Electrical Charges?

Tags: gauss-law, boundary-conditions

So I've read quite a few papers recently claiming that if you have a system with periodic boundary conditions, there are no electrical charges. I'm trying to better understand why this is the case. Basically, there are no charges on toroidal geometries. My intuition is that you can't have one electrical charge because then the periodic boundary conditions imply you really have an infinite number of charges. Does anyone have a better explanation for why this is the case?

Comment: Related: [Coulomb interaction on a ring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461259). My answer to that question includes some math/intuition about the situation in any number of dimensions, including 3d space.